# How do I get a custom action to go to the right place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm sure I'm just missing something simple and stupid, but I  can't figure out how to get my 'account/signup' action working.

This is what I have in my routs file:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.root :controller => "home"
```

I've added this to my accounts controller:

```
def signup
  @account = Account.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # signup.html.erb
    format.xml  { @account }
  end
end
```

And I've added signup.html.erb to the accounts views folder.

Yet when I go to it in the browser I get this error:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#show**
*Couldn't find Account with ID=signup*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should look into using restful routes.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code right on top of your routes.rb file

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect 'account/signup', :controller => 'account', :action => 'signup'
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

Also I think you mean Account and not Accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip:

If you run `rake routes` it'll show you all the possible routes for your app.
It should then be obvious depending on what URL you are entering whether it'll be correctly resolved or not.

For a good overview of routes read this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). There's really a lot of stuff you can do with routes so it's worth taking some time to read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the REST model, you controller should be called **sessions** and your signup action should be **new**, so in your routes you could do :

```
map.resources :sessions
```

This website is highly recommended to all newcomers to Rails :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

The following will do as well when added to the do |map| section of routes.rb

```
map.resource :account, :member => {:signup => :get}
```

Will create the standard routes for your accounts controller, as well as add the new route account/signup. It also provides the usual url helpers in addition to `signup_account_url` and `signup_account_path`